# SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0) | How to resolve this with pgAdmin4/PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, pgadmin-4

Getting SSL SYSCALL error: No error (0x00000000/0) in pgAdmin4 when trying to access schemas in my database. Here is what is looks like:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved the error by disconnecting the database and connecting again in pgadmin.

Don't know how to do it?

You can right-click on your database and choose 'Disconnect' to disconnect and then click on the database to reconnect.

Sharing an image of the options:

[image]